# How to query GitHub deployments using GraphQL and use createdAt as a property?

Tags: github, deployment, graphql, octokit-js

I would like to query my organization deployments using GraphQL and use createdAt as a property (I am doing the same thing with a pull request query : `createdAt:"2022-01-01..2022-01-31"`).

For now, the only way I've found would be to iterate over my repositories, sort deployments by creation date, and stop the query if I reached my limit but I don't think that's efficient.

```
{
  repository(owner: "my_organization", name: "my_repo") {
    deployments(orderBy: {field: CREATED_AT, direction: ASC}) {
      edges {
        node {
          state
          createdAt
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```